# Why am I getting this error while using sikuli on for the first time?

Tags: java, eclipse, sikuli

I've learned how to implement and use sikuli on eclipse using java yesterday for automation testing purposes.
On the first try of running the code I got this error -

[error] RunTimeINIT: *** BE AWARE: Running on Java 8+ *** Please report problems ***

followed by -

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ImageMissing: ‪C:\sekuli\sekuli.png

[The code I currently use and the full errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zteu.png)

```
package sekuli;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

import com.tigervnc.rfb.screenTypes;
public class EX1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed, InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\נייד\\Desktop\\Tools\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.jobmaster.co.il/");
        
        Screen scn = new Screen();
        scn.click("‪C:\\sekuli\\sekuli.png");
        }
}
```

I've imported sikuli version 1.1.3 jars to eclipse.
I tried moving the picture to different directories (although I believe the "missing file" error derives from the initial "RunTimeINIT" error)
I am using a 64-bit system runnig windows 8.1 and have Java 8 installed.

Are there anymore details I can provide to help you guys give me assistance?

Comment: [Please do not post images of your code.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

1.1.3 is no longer supported.
Use 2.0.5.
Recommended: With Java programming use a Maven or Gradle project.

RaiMan from SikuliX